# Update Angular model with jQuery value

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Hi I have an input field which is attached my model and when the user manually types into it a function is called upon change - this works fine and the model is reflecting as expected in the console log.

```
<input type="text" class="rating" ng-model="review.Rating" ng-change="change()" />
```

The issue I now have is that I have a second jQuery function which can be called by the User on the page which auto-populates the input field, but that doesn't seem to trigger an update of the model only the visual value of the input field.

I have therefore added to that second jQuery the following call to trigger an update (based on my research this should be correct)

```
$(".rating").trigger('input');
```

This seems to work fine in Firefox and Chrome as I have it reflecting the model in the console log however in IE (I have 11 - unsure of older browsers) the trigger input doesn't seem to work on updating the model.

Hope you can help.

Answer (score 2):

updated answer:

I think that it does not work, because Angular is probably not aware of the change. Try to call $scope.$digest() after you update the model or add the function inside of $scope.$apply(function() { $.....});

---

Instead of using jQuery, you can just add a function in your controller which assigns the value to the ng-model.

e.g.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="data.input" />
<button ng-click="autoFill()">Click me</button>
```

and in your controller

```
$scope.autoFill = function() {
    $scope.data.input = "Hello World!";
};
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. The problem I would have with that is the second jQuery function does a few more things around the page, one of which is to update that review value in the model. So that's why I was looking for a way within that function to update the model - it seemed that trigger should (and does in chrome and firefox) update the model but doesnt in IE.

I will give your suggestion some thought and see if I can perhaps separate that aspect of the function out

Comment: Ok :) . I think that it does not work, because Angular is probably not aware of the change. Try to call $scope.$digest() after you update the model or add the function inside of $scope.$apply(function() { $.....});

Answer (score 2):

Since, you are updating the text field value outside of Angular's context, you need to tell Angular to reload the changes in `$scope`. So if you have access to scope variable, directly call `$apply()` after setting the value of input field via jQuyery:

```
$scope.$apply();
```

But if you don't have access to `$scope`, you can use any of the parent element or the input field itself to get the scope:

Suppose your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="foo">
    <input type="text" class="rating" ng-model="review.Rating" ng-change="change()" />
</div>
```

Then do this:

```
angular.element(document.querySelector("#foo")).scope().$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-focus instead of ng-change