# What is the difference between set value directly to $scope and via jquery value?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here I created sample text box value binding which is working fine. if I Enter value directly in text box 0,1,2,3 it will update the value fine. I created one submit button if I clicked I updated text box Model inside the function

like this

```
$scope.testing=function() {
    $scope.selected = 0;
}
```

That time it update fine.

But Tried same through jquery value but that time its fails may i know reason why its fail to update. text box value change but not update in model

```
$scope.testing=function() {
    $('#tabId').val(3);
}
```

[Sample here](http://plnkr.co/edit/WdkbX28kOLzdCv4cwGN6?p=preview)

Comment: why you wanted updated that from `jQuery`? it is failing because you are updating value attribute & not scope variable which is bounded to that DOM.. Although you could fix it by having `$scope.testing=function(){$('#tabId').scope().selected = 0;}` also move jQuery above angular [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WWD1vkEV2cfP4xChzj12?p=preview)

Comment: Because that is not in the scope of angular and angular doesn't get notified, for this you have to run the digest cycle with `$apply` method.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is angular doesn't aware of the update made by jquery plugin so if you are updating any value using Jquery and also want model to be updated then you will have to add code for that. It is not going to be automatically.

In your case you will have to modify

```
$scope.testing=function()
  {
    $('#tabId').val(3);
  }
```

with

```
$scope.testing=function()
  {
    $('#tabId').val(3);
    $scope.selected = 3;
  }
```

Similar kind of question was asked in [Model not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22612650/ng-model-is-not-updating-when-using-jquery-element-val).

You can also refer this link [How to update model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30070712/update-angular-model-with-jquery-value).

Hope this helps you.